# Ubuntu's stopped playing music/video files & Youtube

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, flash, youtube

Two days ago (after an Ubuntu base update, iirc), all music and video files on my computer stopped playing. Clementine and Videos open them, but won't play them - no error message, no request for plugins.
At the same time, YouTube clips have stopped playing - I just get the thumbnail, the rotating "waiting" sign and the message "if playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device" (which, of course, doesn't work).
This is Ubuntu 14.04.
Details:

- I do have gstreamer0.10-plugins-good and ubuntu-restricted-extras. Tried reinstalling (together with Clementine and Videos) - no good.
- Videos can clearly "read" the video file, since I can navigate through it and the still picture shown changes.
- My speakers are recognised.
- Pressing "pause" then "play" again doesn't work.
- Flash sound does work! Interestingly enough, right after the update, I could get no sound on clips streamed in a Flash window (they were running though, the video was fine). After restarting, the sound from streaming works just fine, but music/video files and YouTube clips don't.
- I didn't install anything new or make any changes to Ubuntu before this happened.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Solved!**
This is what worked:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
```

Wait a little, then

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Then restart. Ta-dah!
Now how to mark this "solved"...

Comment: To mark this as solved, accept your answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: I can fix this with just the first command, no restart needed. But what could be the cause of this? it happens all the time in my 18.04 and I have to fix it as said. (Created a launcher with the line `Exec=sh -c 'killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*'`.) It seems related to bluetooth headset connection in my case.

Comment: Is there a permanent solution to this?

Comment: None that I've found, I'm afraid. My only lead is something so silly I can only assume it's a coincidence: the problem stopped appearing when I set Firefox to no longer restore my session at startup. I've since changed laptops and moved on to Ubuntu 16.04, so it will probably remain a mystery.

Comment: @mujina In my case audio works from web app like youtube but local mp3 files are unable to play. After using your solution it works but I have to do it multiple times and every time restarting is not possible. can you help me with this?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know what to say. Does this happen in any player? In which case, perhaps a purge & reinstall of pulseaudio? I'm no Ubuntu expert, though.

Comment: This is still an issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Resolution still works, though

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but since I am still affected by this issue in Ubuntu 22.04 and since I haven't able to find anywhere a solution, I am posting it here.

Killing `pulseaudio` didn't work for me, but killing `pipewire` and `pipewire-media session` did.

So, long story short, if killing `pulseaudio` doesn't work for you too, just try to kill `pipewire` and `pipewire-media-session`.