# Videos loading but not playing

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, video

When I try to watch mp4 videos they play with no problem at first, but after a while of watching a couple videos they load, but I can't play them with motion and its stuck on pause even when the play symbol is on, I can skip through the video parts to see pictures of the video though but it doesn't play. I'm using lubuntu and my kernel is Linux Roedelius 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, ubuntu 18.04 bionic

I'd appreciate any help with this. This has only been happening recently after an update.

Comment: Its a well known bug that videos won't play if you use a Bluetooth device (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1589008). If that is the case, checkout https://askubuntu.com/a/1202186/247771 to fix it.

Comment: Check if that's the same as: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/956065/ubuntus-stopped-playing-music-video-files-youtube

Answer (score 0):

If issue appears only on specific video files, then the file is corrupted fixing it might not be possible and or you would have to buy software which fixes corrupted video files, you can confirm corruption by trying to watch video which had issues using different media player, if the issue appears again on different media player, then the file is corrupted.

Also if you pirated the videos, make sure that their downloads are completed, videos which are still being downloaded to the hard drive can be played only partially untill download is at least 90% complete.