# Videos do not play?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video

Since two days, I can't play YouTube videos. They just hang forever. At some point I get a message like this

> If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device.

[image]

I tried this in Chrome and in Firefox. Both hang forever.
I can actually skip through the video and see different images, but I can't play the video.

I have the same issue with local files that I open with the `Videos` application.

What may I do to fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 since a year or so and never had this issue before.

Comment: If you install Chromium from the Ubuntu repositories, and test before adding any extensions, does this problem occur?

Comment: @K7AAY yes, I installed Chromium just for the first time and exactly the same issue as in the other browsers. I also found this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039176/videos-loading-but-not-playing where someone had the same issue 2 years ago.

Comment: askubuntu.com/questions/1039176/videos-loading-but-not-playing doesn't have much of an answer. 1) May I please ask if the files on your local drive played AOK before this issue began? 2) Are those local files from YouTube or another source? 3) Also, would you please test the local files with VLC https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en_GB.html and advise if the problem occurs with VLC? VLC is in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @K7AAY the videos do suddenly work now. I will write back if the issue re-occures and then check if it works with vlc. Pretty sure it will hang again soon.

Comment: @K7AAY I finally found the problem. In Ubuntu, its a known bug that videos won't work if you connect to a Bluetooth device: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1589008

Comment: And here is how I solved the issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1202186/247771